# AWS EC2 Instance Reverse DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2019

I have 3 brand new Windows Server 2019 EC2 instances as follows:

1: Active Directory and DNS configured
2: Vanilla EC2 Instance added to AD
3: Vanilla EC2 Instance added to AD

When I do a reverse DNS lookup on either 2 or 3, the AWS Private DNS name is returned instead of the AD/DNS name. How can I get Windows to use the AD DNS instead of AWS Private DNS?

I having issues with an application doing a reverse DNS lookup to get hostname and it is return the private DNS and therefore not correctly authenticating with AD since the AWS DNS is not in AD.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using the default DNS that you get from your DHCP Options ("second" address on your network). You could make a new set of options and assign that to your instances or push the change manually into them.